# Load URL from Windows command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I want to load a url in a normal windows command line bat script. I know how to do it in powershell but I can't use it for this particular implementation.

```
$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("http://www.google.com")
$response = $request.GetResponse()
$response.Close()
```

I know you can use:

```
start www.google.com
```

But this opens a tab in the default browser. I don't want to open it in a browser. I just want the page to load.

How do I acomplish this?

Comment: You would need a tool like curl.

Comment: What do you mean by "loading the page"? Loading it where?

Comment: Just wait for it to load and then close like the powershell script

Comment: Is the jscript/vbscript an option?

Comment: Why are you unable to use PowerShell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [BITSAdmin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362813%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) tool, or any wget/curl ports to windows

Comment: +1.But you'll have to get the response from temp files created by `bitsadmin.exe` .

Answer (score 2):

You can try [wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) or [curl](http://blog.abelcallejo.com/2013/09/making-curl-work-on-windows-7.html):

```
> curl www.google.com
```

And [here](http://www.discoposse.com/index.php/2012/06/30/powershell-invoke-restmethod-putting-the-curl-in-your-shell/) suggested another method specifically for power shell (from 3.0): **Invoke-RestMethod**. So try:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri www.google.com -Method Get -OutFile C:\Temp\google.html
```